# Remove Single Quotes in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, composer-php

I'm using Composer to run some Bash / Shell commands.

So what im trying to do is replace 'database_name_here' with '$_ENV['DB_NAME']'.

```
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "sed -i.bak 's/database_name_here/$_ENV['DB_NAME']/g' public/wp-config.php"
    ]
```

It starts off as this

```
define('DB_NAME', 'database_name_here');
```

This is the outcome that im getting.

```
define('DB_NAME', '$_ENV[DB_NAME]');
```

But it needs to be like this (Without the single quotes around $_ENV[DB_NAME])

```
define('DB_NAME', $_ENV[DB_NAME]);
```

Is there anything that I can do to make the sed command recognise the single quotes and remove them.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks, Jake.

Answer (score 2):

You can get `sed` to recognize and replace single quotes by using `\x27` instead of explicit single quotes:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\x27database_name_here\x27/$_ENV[DB_NAME]/g' test.txt
```

Given this input:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'database_name_here');
```

the output is:

```
define('DB_NAME', $_ENV[DB_NAME]);
```

Alternatively, you could just use double quotes for the outside delimiters:

```
sed -i.bak "s/'database_name_here'/$_ENV[DB_NAME]/g" test.txt
```

Or another alternative, keeping single quotes on the outside, is to use double quotes to isolate the inner single quotes:

```
sed -i.bak 's/'"'"'database_name_here'"'"'/$_ENV[DB_NAME]/g' test.txt
```

A similar solution uses a backslash to escape a single quote between isolated quotations:

```
sed -i.bak 's/'\''database_name_here'\''/$_ENV[DB_NAME]/g' test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for that, this is the error that i get -> [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
  "./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON
  Parse error on line 23:
  ...g.php",            "sed -i.bak 's/\x27d
  ---------------------^
  Invalid string, it appears you have an unescaped backslash at: \x - It appears you have an extra
   trailing comma

Comment: I am not sure I understand where the error is coming from... I just copied the line from my answer into a Bash shell and it worked there....

Comment: I have added a couple of alternative solutions.

Comment: Good effort on the answer. I have no clue where the issue he is experiencing lies, but I suspect it has to do with using **bash** to preform a substitution within a **php-composer** command to change a **json** array -- what could possibly go wrong....

Comment: @DavidBowling Thanks for updating your answer, I have tried the above methods and none seem to work using the Bash function within php-composer.

Comment: @DavidC.RankinYes you are correct that is what I'm trying to do and make a WordPress Installer script as automatic as possible. I have had a lot of headaches with this. After looking at it a little more it might make sense to abandon using the scripts in composer and just creating an init.sh that you can run once and it will have the desired effect. Then I can add bash commands properly instead of being wrapped in double quotes. Thank you, both for your suggestions.